# Unable to create logger Tomcat Error

Tags: java, tomcat

I have jdk 1.7
path,classpath,catalina_home are set

this was the error

```
E:\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin>tomcat7.exe
The system cannot find the path specified.
Unable to create logger at ''
[2014-11-23 23:03:48] [error] [ 7388] Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java
\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2014-11-23 23:03:48] [error] [ 7388] The system cannot find the path specified.

[2014-11-23 23:03:48] [error] [ 7388] ServiceStart returned 1
[2014-11-23 23:03:48] [error] [ 7388] The system cannot find the path specified.

[2014-11-23 23:03:48] [error] [ 7388] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit va
lue: 3 (Failed to run service as console application)
[2014-11-23 23:03:48] [error] [ 7388] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The system cannot find the path specified.
Failed to run service as console application
E:\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\bin>

Comment: Is jvm.dll present at this location C:\Program Files\Java
\jre7\bin\server?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Here is what I was able to figure out:
This error happens because you don't have the privilege to modify the E:\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\logs directory.  In my case, it was because I installed Tomcat by doing starting a CMD shell in "Run as administrator" mode (which forces you to log in as an administrator), and then doing "unzip apache-tomcat-7.0.57-windows-x64.zip".  This seems to not set up the permissions necessary for the files to be accessed correctly by the service installer even when running in the "Run as administrator" privilege.

Now, if I go to my normal user account CMD shell and unzip the .zip file, and then go back to the administrator CMD shell and run service install , it works.

In fact, if I make a copy of the apache-tomcat-7.0.57 directory using COPY /S/D, and then try to install from that directory, it also works when you do a service install as an administrator.

Hope this helps.